# Ionic Capacitor - Screenshot to Gallery (iOS)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Haven't been able to find any solution to this.

I'm using Ionic Framework 5+ and using Capacitor 3+.

I need to be able to have the user take a screenshot on iOS and Android and have that screenshot automatically saved to the users photo gallery.  Android works just fine with the following code.  iOS also works, however it saves the file in a temporary directory so I need to move the file to whatever directory it needs to go to on iOS so the user can see it in their photo gallery.

```
import { Screenshot } from '@ionic-native/screenshot/ngx';

this.screenshot.save('jpg', 80).then((res) => {
  this.filePath = res.filePath;
  console.log(this.filePath);
});
```

Is there a way to use the FileSystem Capacitor API to save this photo at this `this.filePath` to the iOS gallery?

Is there another way to go from screenshot to gallery on iOS?

Comment: I will ask a (maybe) stupid question, but do you have all the permissions required on iOS (like storage)?

Comment: It's not a stupid question. I can confirm all relevant permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for iOS.  I'm using it in production at the moment.  The fundamental problem had to do with the fact that the Capacitor Community Media library wasn't documented very well to specify exact formatting needed to make it work.  This is the working `package.json` version of the library: `"@capacitor-community/media": "github:dragermrb/media"`.

```
this.screenshot.save().then(async (res) => {

  const savePhotoResult = await Media.savePhoto({
    path: `file://${res.filePath}`,
    album: this.album.identifier
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

On iOS the gallery is something external from your app and can't be accessed through the Filesystem plugin because there is no path to it (and even if there was, iOS apps are sandboxed, you can't access other apps, only your app contents)

You can save a native UIImage to the gallery with this native code:

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(yourImage, nil, nil, nil)` but you have a native path, not an UIImage, so you'll have to convert the path to UIImage first, with something like `let yourImage = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: imagePath)`. So, with that code you can create a plugin that send the path and saves the image to the gallery.

You can also search for plugins that already do that.
There is this one that saves a base64 string that represents an image into the gallery
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64-to-gallery

There is also capacitor-community/media that has a savePhoto function, which takes a path and saves the photo to the gallery

https://github.com/capacitor-community/media#api

Comment: The first plugin seems to be deprecated and no longer maintained- it has issues with latest version of Ionic and Capacitor.  The second capacitor-community doesn't work on Capacitor v3+ and throws errors on iOS.